# Virtual Button is pressed by itself in unity although I try setting the sensitivity level a bit lower

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

This is my situation:

[image]

I have been working on the project and the virtual button is pressed by itself. I tried setting the sensitivity level a bit lower, but it still does not work!

How can I fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class Bu : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{
  public GameObject button1;
  public GameObject Sphere;

  void Start()
  {
    button1 = GameObject.Find("button1");
    Sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");

    button1.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);

  }

  public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
  {
    Debug.Log("Pressed");
  }

  public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
  {
    Debug.Log("Released");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some more background here on what your trying to do. As is, there's not enough information to solve your problem